# How to display data in below format

Tags: sql

My table is:

```
Id    Name        Add
1     a           A
2     b           B
3     c           C
4     d           D
```

I want to displaty it as:

```
Id    Name        Add        Id2        Name2        Add2
1     a           A          2          b            B
3     c           C          4          d            D
```

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how i can do this

Comment: Rdbms? What is the logic?

Comment: Give it a try.. and then we could help further..

Comment: I want to extract two tables... one with odd Id and another with even Id and then join them

Comment: Is it sql server or mysql? Are IDs sequantial?

Answer (score 1):

Use query below

```
Select LTable.id,LTable.Name,LTable.[Add],
       RTable.id,RTable.Name,RTable.[Add]
from
(
    Select Row_Number()over ( order by id)as fldkey,id,name , [Add]
    from TableName
    where id % 2 <> 0
) as LTable INNER JOIN
(
    Select Row_Number()over ( order by id)as fldkey,id,name , [Add]
    from TableName 
    where id % 2 = 0
) as RTable
on LTable.fldKey = RTable.fldKey
```